# Creating independent stopwatches for each item in array. Setting the stopped time, based on data returned by the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Creating independent stopwatches. I have two elements named `A` and`B`. When I click on the `A` element, its description`Hello` and stopwatch will appear. When I click on the `B` element, its`World` description and stopwatch will appear. I have a problem with stopwatches. When I click on the element `A` and start the stopwatch, go to the element`B` then this stopwatch is running. My goal is that when I run the stopwatch for the element `A` it will count only for this element. When he stops the stopwatch in the element `A`, and go to the element`B`, then in this element the stopwatch will count only for this element. I stop the stopwatch in the `B` element and go to the`A` element and I will be able to resume the stopwatch. I am asking for some ideas to solve this problem. 
I send by calling the startTime function (method post -> object with the starting date). I click stop -> calls stopTimer (method post -> I send the object with the end date). In response, the item is debossed with the starting date and end date and the number of seconds (the difference between the end date and the starting date) is saved in the state. On the basis of these data (start date, end date and second), set the time at which the stopwatch was stopped. How do I close my browser to download this data to set the time at which it was stopped.
Please, give me some tips. I will correct my code on a regular basis and insert it here.

**Expected effect:**

Click element `A` -> start stopwatch -> stopwatch stop -> click element`B` -> start stopwatch -> return to element `A` -> resume the timer on the time it was stopped

The whole code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x9h42z

Part of the code:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      items: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello'
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          description: 'World'
        }
      ],
      selectIndex: null
    };
  }

  select = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      selectIndex: index
    })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selectIndex)
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items
              .map((item, index) =>
                <Item
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                  select={this.select}
                  items = {this.state.items}
                  selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
         <ItemDetails
            items = {this.state.items}
            selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}

        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Stopwatch**

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  resetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    });
  };

  render() {
      const { timerTime } = this.state;
      let centiseconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
      let seconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
      let minutes = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
      let hours = ("0" + Math.floor(timerTime / 3600000)).slice(-2);

    return (
      <div>


    <div className="Stopwatch-display">
      {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds} : {centiseconds}
    </div>


    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime === 0 && (
    <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
    )}

    {this.state.timerOn === true && (
      <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
    )}

    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Resume</button>
    )}

    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>
    )}
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stopwatch does not update as your render method always returns `<Stopwatch />`,
so even if `selectItem` changes react does not render a new `<Stopwatch />` component
for you, it shows the old one.

```
return (
  <div>
    {selectItem ?
      <div>
        <p>Description:{selectItem.description}</p>
        <Stopwatch />
      </div>
      :
      null
    }
  </div>
)
```

For react to render a new component for you you need to pass a `key` property to your
component.

```
return (
  <div>
    {selectItem ?
      <div>
        <p>Description:{selectItem.description}</p>
        <Stopwatch key={selectItem.name}/>
      </div>
      :
      null
    }
  </div>
)
```

Now react renders new component for you when you switch between stopwatches, but
every time you do that stopwatch resets, as the component itself it re-rendered
initializing your state variables.

This is where state management pops in. You can use REDUX to manage your component state.
You can also write a simple service to do it for you if you want your stopwatch to run
in the background.

**Demo:** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ast5c2).

Answer (score 5):

What you need is to create two instances of stopwatches one for each list item. I have made changes to the link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lxnd5g) you provided.
I added stopwatch in your list array to each object with a unique key for React to know that they are a different component.
Now, I am simply rendering all the list items with stopwatches and to maintain the state of each stopwatch even after the switch I am just using a simple display none technique rather than removing the component altogether.
Check the code and let me know if it works for you?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';


class Item extends Component {

  render() {
    const selectItem = this.props.items[this.props.selectIndex]
    console.log(selectItem);
    
    return ( 
      
        <li onClick={() => this.props.select(this.props.index)}>
          <div>
            Name:{this.props.item.name}
          </div>
        </li>
    )
  }
}

class ItemDetails extends Component {
 
  render() {
    const selectItem = this.props.items[this.props.selectIndex]
    console.log(selectItem);
    let content = this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div className={this.props.selectIndex === index?'show':'hide'}>
          <p>
              Description:{item.description}
          </p>
          {item.stopWatch}
        </div>
      );
    })
    return (  
      <div>
        {selectItem ?
            content
          :
          null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      items: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello',
          stopWatch: <Stopwatch key={1} />
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          description: 'World',
          stopWatch: <Stopwatch key={2} />
        }
      ],
      selectIndex: null
    };
  }

  select = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      selectIndex: index
    })
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.selectIndex)
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items
              .map((item, index) =>
                <Item
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  item={item}
                  select={this.select}
                  items = {this.state.items}
                  selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
         <ItemDetails
            items = {this.state.items}
            selectIndex = {this.state.selectIndex}

        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Stopwatch extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  resetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    });
  };

  render() {
      const { timerTime } = this.state;
      let centiseconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
      let seconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
      let minutes = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
      let hours = ("0" + Math.floor(timerTime / 3600000)).slice(-2);

    return (
      <div>
      

    <div className="Stopwatch-display">
      {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds} : {centiseconds}
    </div>


    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime === 0 && (
    <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
    )}

    {this.state.timerOn === true && (
      <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
    )}

    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Resume</button>
    )}
    
    {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>
    )}
        </div>
      );
    }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I checked it. But if I turn on the clock for the element `A` and go to the element` B` then the clock is the same for both. The clock is going. And it should be 00:00:00 to go to element B. They should indicate different times.  I stopped the element 'A' to '02: 00 'and went to the element `B` and I see '02: 00', and it should be 00:00

Comment: Ok, I guess the editor didn't persist the code. Let me do it again and will post the code. Here

Comment: Yeah, there's some error in Stackoverflow way of things. Paste the code in your editor and it will work. cheers! I wasn't able to persist my changes on the url you shared that's why I shared here

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually have several stop watches (one for each item) but show only one of them (which is the selected one)

On the `ItemDetails` component, Replacing:

```
<Stopwatch />
```

with

```
{this.props.items.map((_, index) => (
  <div style={{ display: index === this.props.selectIndex ? "block" : "none" }}>
    <Stopwatch />
  </div>
))}
```

Will solve your problem as showed here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-atci76

That way react is taking care of two stop watches (cycle and states and all) but your HTML is only showing one of them.

Alternatively, if you are going to show lots of stopwatches, you can have one Stopwatch state passed as property to your Stopwatch object and then switch the state using the button

Comment: @Umbro sure, React is rendering at every timer update. You can navigate to other tabs and see that it keeps running

Comment: I create chrome extension in React. It doesn't work.  Would you be able to set it to localstorage?

Comment: You should have said you'd need it for a chrome extension. Chrome extension works differently from normal HTML. You should make like here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages so you can make your script run on the background

Comment: And not just save it to local.storage?

Comment: You can certainly store the timers object in the localStorage. But the problem you are seeing is that your script is stop being executed once it enters the background. Using localStorage won't interfere on this problem

Comment: Have you ever created such an extension?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**:

You composition is wrong. Even though you are rendering one `<Item />` for each element of the state your `<ItemDetails />` is only called once, so the state will be always the same, doesn't matter which item is current selected. This is happening because your component `<ItemDetails />` knows all details and only changes between then, not changing the `Stopwatch />` component.

**Possible Solution**

There is actually a few alternatives to this problem, my favorite is:

**Make the `Item` component standalone**:

You could, instead of having one component to display details of the current selected user, have single component which knows how to display it's details an knows the state of it's own `<Stopwatch />` and only show details and stopwatch if is selected. Something like this:

```
class Item extends Component {

  render() {
    const selectItem = this.props.items[this.props.selectIndex]
    console.log(selectItem);

    return ( 

        <li onClick={() => this.props.select(this.props.index)}>
          <div>
            Name:{this.props.item.name}
          </div>
          {this.props.isSelected ?
              <div>
                  <p>
                      Description:{selectItem.description}
                  </p>
                     <Stopwatch />
              </div>
               :

               null
        }
        </li>
    )
  }

}
```

This way you have a decoupled way of dealing with multiple items with different times.

> This is actually not exactly what you are looking for, cause even like this you still have your `Stopwatches` components beeing mounted and unmounted so the state gets reseted everytime, to workaround this you need a way to "remember" the previous state of each counter or never unmount then, just hide those who aren't selected.

I've altered your fiddle to reflect 2 `<Stopwatch />` [running separately](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1d9txa?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `Stopwatch` component to store timers by a label name.

The `Stopwatch` will have a `label` prop. 
When the label changes you could store the current timer and load a new one. 
The new one can be an empty one or one that is already known, loaded from state.

```
class Stopwatch extends Component {
  // moved the empty timer for easy reusing
  defaultTimer = {
    timerOn: false,
    timerStart: 0,
    timerTime: 0,
    time: {
      startTime: "",
      endTime: "",
      seconds: ""
    }
  };

  state = {
    // We store the saved timers in here. 
    // For convenience of finding the I used an object to save them
    knownTimers: {},
    ...this.defaultTimer
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // when the label changes
    if (prevProps.label !== this.props.label) {
      const { knownTimers, timerOn, timerStart, timerTime, time } = this.state;
      // we stop any running timers
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      // we build the _timer_ we want save
      const knownTimerToSave = { timerOn, timerStart, timerTime, time };
      // if the label identifies a known _timer_ we load that one
      // if not we load a new timer
      const loadedTimer = knownTimers[this.props.label]
        ? knownTimers[this.props.label]
        : this.defaultTimer;

      this.setState({
        // we load the current timer
        ...loadedTimer,
        // we overwrite `knownTimers` with the save timers
        knownTimers: {
          ...knownTimers,
          [prevProps.label]: {
            ...knownTimerToSave,
            // we make sure we don't save a running timer
            timerOn: false
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  resetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { timerTime } = this.state;
    let centiseconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
    let seconds = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
    let minutes = ("0" + (Math.floor(timerTime / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
    let hours = ("0" + Math.floor(timerTime / 3600000)).slice(-2);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Stopwatch-display">
          {hours} : {minutes} : {seconds} : {centiseconds}
        </div>

        {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime === 0 && (
          <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
        )}

        {this.state.timerOn === true && (
          <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>Stop</button>
        )}

        {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
          <button onClick={this.startTimer}>Resume</button>
        )}

        {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime > 0 && (
          <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If the label changed when a timer is running this is automatically turned off.

In order for this to work `Stopwatch` must be rendered once - not displayed conditionally. When the component unmounts the state clears and you loose all the known timers.

Here is [demo of the component in action](https://codesandbox.io/s/stopwatch-example-xm1yy)

There are other ways to accomplish this. Hope this helps!